# Show a page to tell users to check their connection on PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

im Working with PhoneGap, im building an application with connection mode,
and i want to show for users to check their internet when they are offline to use the my app, how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

- `navigator.onLine`, see [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) for details.
- The [Network Information](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html) plugin lets you check if there is a connection available, and if so, what type of connection is in use (but you should not rely on the connection type — there are lots of ways the connection type can mislead you.)

However, you should not rely on these to determine if your app has a connection to your backend. Short of having no connection whatsoever, you should always attempt to route to your host, since having a connection doesn't guarantee that your host is reachable. The host could be down, or the user could be behind a network that doesn't let them out.

As to the user interface, that's entirely up to you. Avoid lots of technical verbage, and keep the message simple but clear.